# Change target="_blank" to target = "_self" for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying this code:

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
  // The viewport is less than 768 pixels wide 
  document.getElementById("link").target = "_self";
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="/something" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

But it's working for only one id. I want to convert `target="_blank"` to `target = "_self"` for all the links in web page using one class or ID.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ID is unique. That means you can only have one element with a specific ID. You can't give this ID to another element. Therefore you should use your second approach: classes

In this code, you get all elements with the specific class and then set it's targets to `_self`.

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].target = "_self";
}
```

HTML example:

```
<a class="className" href="/something" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since id's have to be unique, we can use `document.querySelectorAll("a[id^=link]").target = "_self"`

`a[id^=link]` will select all `links(a)` where the id stats with `link`

**Demo**

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
  // The viewport is less than 768 pixels wide 
  document.querySelectorAll("a[id^=link]").target = "_self"
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="/something" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
<a id="link2" href="/something" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```